# How to run Blazor client side when running backend in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, blazor

I have two visual studio projects, one an asp net core api and one a client side blazor app. As part of the production build I copy the output of the blazor app into the `/wwwroot` folder of the asp net app.

But locally I have to build it and copy the files or have a test index.html in the `/wwwroot` directory.

How can I make Visual Studio build the blazor project and copy it to the wwwroot folder automatically when I 'press play' in visual studio to run my backend?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up a Post Build Event command for your backend project.  You can do this by right-clicking on your project in Solution Explorer and opening the Properties window.  On the left menu, you will see "Build Events".  From there you can see two windows with your Pre-build command line and your Post-build command line.  View more information here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019 . The syntax is a little tricky but there are lots of examples online for copying files into directories after successful builds.  Hope this helps, good luck!